# Eshop - adding to cart not working properly

Tags: php, html, firefox, safari, cart

my cousin, who owns e-shop asked me to check and solve the issue with adding goods to cart, however I have not been able to found solution yet. He made some updates to website, but I have no idea what exactly it was. So, if customer is using Chrome/Firefox, everything works like a charm. However, the problem is just with Safari browser. If you visit website for the first time (after update), everything works properly, but, if you have already visited before update, now you will not be able to add smth into it. After adding, cart will remains empty. 
Does anybody know, what may cause this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Different browsers mostly have problems with javascript (functionality) and css (display). The PHP doesn't care about your browser and if its faulty, it would be for all browsers. You should check the errors in browser console (etc. Firebug, F12) after a browser action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Cookie lifetime was changed from 10000 to 3600